# Show frame/margin in two column layout

Tags: margins, two-column

How can I show the frames for inter-column margin under the `twocolumn` document class option?

The `showframe` package only draws the page margins + headers and footers. But I want to see a line for the margin between two columns.

Comment: `\setlength\columnseprule{0.4pt}`
`

Comment: Are you using [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) or the `twocolumn` class option?

Comment: I'm using twocolumn

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, setlength\columnseprule{0.4pt}  only showed one line in the middle of two columns. I want to know see the margin between two columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option using `\@outputdblcol`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newlength\Fcolumnseprule
\setlength\Fcolumnseprule{0.4pt}

\makeatletter
\def\@outputdblcol{%
  \if@firstcolumn
    \global \@firstcolumnfalse
    \global \setbox\@leftcolumn \box\@outputbox
  \else
    \global \@firstcolumntrue
    \setbox\@outputbox \vbox {%
                         \hb@xt@\textwidth {%
                           \hb@xt@\columnwidth {%
                             \box\@leftcolumn \hss}%
                           \vrule \@width\Fcolumnseprule\hfil
                                {\normalcolor\vrule \@width\columnseprule}%original:
                                                %\normalcolor\vrule \@width\columnseprule
                           \hfil\vrule \@width\Fcolumnseprule
                           \hb@xt@\columnwidth {%
                             \box\@outputbox \hss}%
                                             }%
                              }%
    \@combinedblfloats
    \@outputpage
    \begingroup
      \@dblfloatplacement
      \@startdblcolumn
      \@whilesw\if@fcolmade \fi
        {\@outputpage
         \@startdblcolumn}%
    \endgroup
  \fi
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A patch makes the code shorter:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newlength\Fcolumnseprule
\setlength\Fcolumnseprule{0.4pt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ShowInterColumnFrame{
\patchcmd{\@outputdblcol}
  {{\normalcolor\vrule \@width\columnseprule}}
  {\vrule \@width\Fcolumnseprule\hfil
    {\normalcolor\vrule \@width\columnseprule}
    \hfil\vrule \@width\Fcolumnseprule
  }
  {}
  {}
}

\makeatother
\ShowInterColumnFrame

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```