# Bibliography text is mixed between two columns

Tags: bibliographies, two-column, overleaf

I have a document and I have bib file and citations in the text. The documents information is this:

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\begin{document}
 abstract in one column
\twocolumn
 the article and citations
 \printbibliography
 \end{document}
```

The problem is that in the bibliography section, the references in the two columns sometimes get mixed:

[image: The bibliography section]

Other references are fine, but the only two are the problem. I need to add that the same problem exists through the article in several instances, where a math formula has reached end of the line and cannot be collapsed in the next line. I may be able to handle this by changing that line, but in the references I have no idea what to do.

Thanks.

edit:

The previous code for reference 1 was :

```
@article{morgulis2019fooling,
title={Fooling a real car with adversarial traffic signs},
author={Morgulis, Nir and Kreines, Alexander and Mendelowitz, Shachar 
and Weisglass, Yuval},
journal={arXiv preprint arXiv:1907.00374},
year={2019}
}
```

for reference 3, the issue was resolved only when I manually changed the 3 authors name to the et al. format. I had added this reference manually.

```
@inproceedings{
arjomandi2021limited,
title={Limited Budget Adversarial Attack Against Online Image Stream},
author={Mohasel Arjomandi, Hossein and Khalooi, Mohammad and 
Amirmazlaghani, Maryam},
booktitle={ICML 2021 Workshop on Adversarial Machine Learning},
year={2021},
url={https://openreview.net/forum?id=IjsmgcivXL}
}
```

reference 14 was fine and was not changed:

```
@article{goodfellow2014explaining,
title={Explaining and harnessing adversarial examples},
author={Goodfellow, Ian J and Shlens, Jonathon and Szegedy, Christian},
journal={arXiv preprint arXiv:1412.6572},
year={2014}
}
```

Comment: Well, as you said yourself, this is caused by the system not knowing, when to break the line. The issue exists in your ref 14 as well. In case of the arXiv entries a space between the : and the actual number should to the trick. In the name, try adding a `\-` to the name(s) to give LaTeX some hints on how to hyphenate them.

Comment: Please add the bibentrys 1, 3 and 14 to your question ...

Comment: @MarkusG. The arXiv trick worked well but the names for reference 4 did not work. Maybe because I had added this reference manually? I solved this issue by switching to et al. format because there were 3 authors for that article

Comment: @m0ss You could try adding `\hyphenation{Kha-looi}` to your preamble. This will tell LaTeX how to properly hyphenate this particular name and the problem should dissapear. (No guarantees)

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
```

and

```
\nocite{*} 
\printbibliography
```

you get dozens of overflow boxes per page.

[image: a]

They disappear adding `\raggedright`

```
\nocite{*} 
\raggedright
\printbibliography
```

[image: b]

Using `\defbibenvironment{bibliography}` it is possible to make better use of the space.

```
    \DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\makebox[0pt][l]{[#1]}}
    \defbibenvironment{bibliography}
    {\list{\printfield[labelnumberwidth]{labelnumber}}
        {%
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.8em}%
            \setlength{\labelsep}{2em}%
            \setlength{\itemindent}{-2em}%          
            \addtolength{\itemindent}{\labelsep}%   
            \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
            \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
    {\endlist}
    {\item}
```

[image: e]

This is the complete code.

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}

%%********************************** show two column margins
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271285/show-frame-margin-in-two-column-layout
\newlength\Fcolumnseprule
\setlength\Fcolumnseprule{0.4pt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ShowInterColumnFrame{
    \patchcmd{\@outputdblcol}
    {{\normalcolor\vrule \@width\columnseprule}}
    {\vrule \@width\Fcolumnseprule\hfil
        {\normalcolor\vrule \@width\columnseprule}
        \hfil\vrule \@width\Fcolumnseprule
    }
    {}
    {}
}

\makeatother
\ShowInterColumnFrame
%%********************************** 

\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}

    \DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\makebox[0pt][l]{[#1]}}
    \defbibenvironment{bibliography}
    {\list{\printfield[labelnumberwidth]{labelnumber}}
        {%
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.8em}%
            \setlength{\labelsep}{2em}%
            \setlength{\itemindent}{-2em}%          
            \addtolength{\itemindent}{\labelsep}%   
            \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
            \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
    {\endlist}
    {\item}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

    abstract in one column
    \twocolumn
    the article and citations
    
    \nocite{*}  
    \raggedright
    \printbibliography
\end{document
```